# Make Django compress with {% static %}

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-compressor, django-static

I'm trying to make django compress work but I believe it does not work because of my `{% static %}` use.

My template is (I'm using pyjade but doesn't matter):

```
- load staticfiles
- load compress

| {% compress css %}
link(rel="stylesheet", href="{% static 'less/bootstrap.css' %} ")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="{% static 'timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css'%}")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="{% static 'leaflet/addons/locatecontrol/L.Control.Locate.css' %} ")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css")
link(href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.css', rel='stylesheet')
| {% endcompress %}
```

And part of my settings.py:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_STORAGE = "staticfiles.storage.StaticFileStorage"

INSTALLED_APPS = (....,'compressor',....)
```

Even if I `$ python manage.py collectstatic` the compress does not work and spits out the original files. In the [docs it says](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/) I should provide the absolute path which I think I have given, haven't I? Can someone help make compress work? Thanks. (I'm not an very familiar with django's static files).

---

**Update**

After following Timmy's comment I enabled `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True` (and `DEBUG=False`) in settings, it still needs to find the files:

```
UncompressableFileError at /
'less/bootstrap.css ' could not be found in the COMPRESS_ROOT '/Users/diolor/mysite/wsgi/static' or with staticfiles.
```

Just to note that the static files are correctly found and rendered (when `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False`).

My structure:

```
mysite/
   wsgi/
      myapp/
         settings.py
         manage.py
         media/
            #js & css files
      static/
         [...]
```

---

After playing some time it looks like compress has trouble with the css and `{% static %}`.

If you have 
`link(rel="stylesheet", href="/static/less/bootstrap.css")` 
it greaty compresses the stylesheets, on 
`link(rel="stylesheet", href="{% static 'less/bootstrap.css' %} ")` it raises an error.

On js, it renders it fine: `script(type="text/javascript", src='{% static "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}')`

Comment: Compressor will only work when `DEBUG=False` or specifically with the setting `COMPRESS=True`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have a space at the end of your href, between `%}` and `"`. If you look at the error message carefully, you'll see that the compressor is looking for a file with a space at the end. (Same thing on the leaflet stylesheet.)